# Расшифровка файла, закодированного SHA-1 имея код

Tags: php, шифрование, sha1

У меня есть зашифрованный в SHA-1 файл и код SHA-1, состоящий примерно из 20 символов (как я понимаю - это ключ).

Как, имея этот ключ, можно расшифровать этот файл? Может быть существует такая функция на PHP?

Comment: Извините, если поставил неправильные метки, потому что я не знаю к какой категории относится этот вопрос)).

Comment: Семейство SHA - НЕ шифр, это хэш. Хэш не имеет обратного преобразования в общем случае. Если у вас есть SHA1 файла и вам надо по хэшу восстановить файл - в общем случае ничего не выйдет.

Comment: Жаль :c. Бедный файлик)

Answer (score 1):

SHA не дешифруется в принципе. В помощь брутфорс, но 20 символов это жесть. :) На это уйдёт примерно 10к веков. К тому времени Бендер украдёт всё во вселенной, включая ваш зашифрованный код. :)

(с) Касперский